# Oracle 10g Insert query performs inconsistent as a query vs procedure and performs differently from time to time

Tags: oracle10g

I am facing a very weird issue that I have a insert statement in a procedure...
pretty much

```
    inert
    into oracle_Table
    SELECT cr.a AS a,       
           cr.b AS b,
           cr.c AS c,
           max(d.column_name) as d
    FROM "table 1"@Pmo.World Cr,
          table2@Pmo.World       d
     WHERE d."a" = cr."column name"
     GROUP BY cr.a,
              cr.b,
              cr.c
```

@Pmo.World is a database link to a MSSQL...

The problem I am having right now is, every time I run this insert as a query. Everything works as what it should be... However, when I put this insert into a procedure, it inserts nothing...

Thinking about character conversion issue I changed the procedure to

```
inert
into oracle_Table
SELECT to_char(cr.a) AS a,       
       to_char(cr.b) AS b,
       to_char(cr.c) AS c,
       max(d.column_name) as d
  FROM "table 1"@Pmo.World Cr,
       table2@Pmo.World       d
 WHERE d."a" = cr."column name"
 GROUP BY cr.a,
          cr.b,
          cr.c
```

Then this Inser works in the procedure... however when I revert it back with the original version that doesnt have to_char... it is working still... then I kept it running for few days... since it runs once per day, it was working for the first 2 days and then stopped working the third day... 
I verified the source table and every time this procedure runs, source tables were not empty...
It is so confusing because if I manually run the insert as a query, it worked every time I ran it... however if I put that into a procedure, it works from time to time..

Comment: What is the datatype of `cr.a`, `cr.b` and `cr.c` ? and what is the datatype of `a`, `b` and `c` ?

Comment: Could it be that you don't always commit ?

Comment: I did have commit following the insert... this got resolved by using materialized view... but the cause still did not get found...

Answer (score 0):

a,b,c have type of varchar2 and I do have commit right after the insert...
for instance
if I have a test procedure

```
declare 
-- Local variables here
i integer;
begin
inert
into oracle_Table
SELECT cr.a AS a, 
cr.b AS b,
cr.c AS c,
max(d.column_name) as d
FROM "table 1"@Pmo.World Cr,
table2@Pmo.World d
WHERE d."a" = cr."column name"
GROUP BY cr.a,
cr.b,
cr.c
end;
commit;
```

Nothing could get inserted